# Can I get auto-completion for words in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

How can I start typing a word, and have Microsoft Word offer me suggestions so I don't need to finish typing?

Is there an addon I can buy or download that would do this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [**Phrase Express**](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) (freeware).

> Organize frequently used text snippets.
>       *Expand abbreviations* as you type.
>       Launch programs with text shortcuts.
>       *Auto-complete repetitive phrases*.
>       Quick access to the Windows Clipboard History.
>       Correct spelling mistakes in any application.

You can also create your own suggestions to auto-complete...Works on Windows, cross-software...

**Also:** [*Alternatives* to Phrase Express.](http://alternativeto.net/software/phraseexpress/)

Answer (score 2):

There is not AutoComplete in built into Word such as you'll find in a web browser or the like simply because the possible words you'll type into a Word Processor is much, much larger than the list of possible words you'll enter into a browser address bar.

Microsoft did re-enable a system called QuickParts or QuickText that allow you to enter a pre-defined code or set of keys which Word will then replace with a longer phrase that you had configured previously.

You can find more information on this built-in system [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/office2010/thread/1eb1dc32-d51a-40a8-bcf5-06464ee7d511/) and [here](http://compusavvy.wordpress.com/2010/02/06/autocomplete-returns-in-word-2010-quick-primer-on-quick-parts/).